# jQuery selector only selects the first element

Tags: jquery, input, css-selectors

I have a small question about using jquery. 
I have the following code:

```
<html> 
<head>

    <script src="jquery/jquery.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
      $("form").submit(function(){
       if(!$(':text').val()){
        $("span").text("sdfgsd").show();

        };return false;
      })
      });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <form action=""  id="ff" >
       <span></span>
        <input type="text" name="test" /> <br />
        <input type="text" name="test3" /> <br />
        <input type="checkbox" name="test2" /> <br />
        <input type="submit" value="push it" />
    </form>

</body>
```

the problem is that the selector is only activated for the first textbox. if you enter a value in the first textbox the trigger is not activated. neither :text or :input work properly.

does anyone have any ideas??

thanx in advance,
denisr

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd suggest you to do something like that:

```
<html> 
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $("#ff").submit(function(e) {
                $('.text-input').each(function() {
                    if ($(this).val() == '') {
                        $("#msg").text("sdfgsd");
                        e.preventDefault();
                        return false;
                    }
                });
            });
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <form method="post" action=""  id="ff">
        <span id="msg"></span>
        <input type="text" class="text-input" name="test" /> <br />
        <input type="text" class="text-input" name="test3" /> <br />
        <input type="checkbox" name="test2" /> <br />
        <input type="submit" value="push it" />
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

- Try to use as much as possible the `id` or `class` attributes to access elements because it's more efficient and less prone to errors
- Use `e.preventDefault()` to prevent from submitting the form
- Use `return false;` to get out of the `each` loop right away

Answer (score 4):

The `val()` function on a jQuery selector matching more than one element returns the value of the first element matched.  You need to loop over all the elements and check the value of each one.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("form").submit(function(){
     var inputsHaveValues = true;
     $(':text').each( function() {
         if (!$(this).val()) {
            inputsHaveValues = false;
            break;
         }
     });

     if (!inputsHaveValues) {
         $("span").text("sdfgsd").show();
         return false;
     }
  })
});
```

Answer (score 4):

`val` is a **destructive** method (you can't chain on to it) and so when applied to an object with many elements in it, has to return a value, which it will do for the first.

You should look at the `each` method to iterate through all your text fields.

```
$('input:text').each(function(index, elm) {
  if(!$(this).val()){
    $("span").text("sdfgsd").show();
  };
});
```

You could use the index to identify a particular `span` in which to show the error message.

Answer (score 1):

Try defining a class applied to each text, defining a form id, or using jquery each.  Also, check for javascript errors.

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#ff").submit(function(event){
        $('input[type="text"]').each(function () {
            if(!$(this).val()){
               $("span").text("Foobar");
            }
        });
       event.preventDefault();
    })
});
```

1. First of all please use
   [`event.preventDefault();`](http://api.jquery.com/event.preventDefault/) its much
   better than `return false;`.
2. Use the id - `$(#ff)` - instant of
   only `$('form')`.
3. Use `input[type="text"]` instant of only `:text`
4. Use [.each()](http://api.jquery.com/each) - like some people above me said

Comment: why do you wanna set the text to the `span` for every text input that's empty, you can use a flag and set it just once.

Comment: @LiLivingston its only for the example :)

Comment: @Lilivingston -- hi, as m0 mentioned is only for example.I am trying to learn and the only way I can learn is through practice...