# jQuery append() is not appending the value from the input:text in the HTML by JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
$(function() {
    var $newform, $newlinks, $addlinks, $list;
    $newform = $('.form-space');
    $newlinks = $('#newlinks');
    $addlinks = $('#addlink');
    $list = $('ul');
    $newform.hide();
    $newlinks.on('click', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $newlinks.hide();
        $newform.show();
    });
    $newform.on('submit', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var text = $('input:text').val();
        $list.append('<a href="https://www.exampleee.com"><li class="links"><span>' + text + '</span></li></a>');
        $('input:text').val('');
    });
});
```

So I was trying to create a clone of linktree, and I'm stuck in appending the value in the text:input when the submit button is clicked. I want to achieve the behavior that if I press the submit button the value in the text:input should be appended to the ul element. Can someone tell me where is the mistake and what I should do.

Comment: `$('input:text')` selects the first text input on the page, not an input in the form being submitted. Is this what you want?

Comment: I suspect you really want `$(this).find('input:text')`

Comment: Why is there a li inside of a link? That does not look like valid HTML

Comment: It is invalid in HTML to have an `a` element wrap an `li` element. The only allowable parents for an `li` element are `ol`, `ul`, and `menu` (and the obsolete `dir`).

Comment: For reference, see [`<ul>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/ul): "Permitted content: Zero or more `<li>`, `<script>` and `<template>` elements."

Comment: Does this answer your question? [jQuery selector only selects the first element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5370887/jquery-selector-only-selects-the-first-element)

Comment: i got the answer thank you everyone i dont know how to reply user in stackoverflow. thank you anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing your exact HTML markup I just tried checking your basic append functionallity and it seems to work fine.

Here is a CodePen to check my test, feel free to share your HTML, maybe the issue lies there.

https://codepen.io/rikkertDE/pen/rNmgEeq

HTML:

```
<form class="form-space">
  <input type="text">
  <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>

<ul>
</ul>
```

JS:

```
$(function() {
  var $newform, $newlinks, $addlinks, $list;
  $newform = $('.form-space');
  $list = $('ul');
  $newform.on('submit', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var text = $('input:text').val();
    $list.append('<a href="https://www.exampleee.com"><li class="links"><span>' + text + '</span></li></a>');
    $('input:text').val('');
  });
});
```

---

Edit:

As Barmar pointed out the problem might lie in the way you are selecting the input field. A better way would be to use an ID, a class or to find it with in the form, e.g.

```
var text = $newform.find('input:text').val();
```

Comment: Why use a codepen instead of stack snippet?

Comment: Well, I have not heard of stack snippet before. I will consider checking it out, thank you.

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do